# getting unsupported proxy error while trying to run npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am not able to install a  certain libraries in npm because everytime I get the following error

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROXY
npm ERR! unsupported proxy protocol: 'proxy.company.com:'
```

I have tried `npm config rm proxy`  and `npm config rm https-proxy` but it is not helping

and I am using my personal internet connection so not sure whether I need a proxy

Comment: Where did you get `npm config rm` from? The relevant option I see in [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-config?v=true) is `npm config delete`. You might also need to use the `--global` option if you have both local and global config

Comment: You can also run `npm config list` to see where each setting is actually defined